# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier always returns nil (not using storyboard)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, deque

I am creating the cell **programatically** using the reuse identifier.

**Note** - I am not using storyboard for creating the cell

Whenever the cell is dequeued, the cell is nil, so the cell needs to be newly created using alloc, which is expensive.

**EDIT (added 1 more question and corrected code)**

**Question**

- Why does this dequeue always return nil ? How can I correct it ?
- Does dequeue work only when used along with storyboard / nib file ?

**Code**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(!cell) //Every time cell is nil, dequeue not working 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How often exactly does it return nil? And how many of those cells are displayed simultanously on your devices screen? Reusing means to re-use those cells only, that were just scrolled off the screen.

Comment: And Srikar is right. The appropriate cell identifier must be set on the newly created cells.

Comment: It returns nil always. 4 cells are displayed at a given time and when I scroll dequeue returns nil.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was making a couple of mistakes:

1. I was using a subclass of `UITableViewController`, but was creating the tableView outside of the subclass
2. There is a `tableView` created in the table view controller, which is `self.tableView` In the tableview controller while returning the cell for index path, I was using `self.tableView` instead of `tableView`.
3. Also, ensure that the cell identifier is declared as `static`

   ```
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   ```

Since `tableView` and `self.tableView` were representing different tables, the cell was not being dequeued from the same table and hence was always `nil`

Comment: Point 2. To completely remove ambiguity I named the `tableView` in my `nib` to `mTableView`.

Answer (score 12):

You need to first set the `CellIdentifier` as `Cell`. Are you doing that? When you are creating a new cell you need to assign this identifier `Cell` to it. only then iOS will be able to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` with that identifier. Programatically you can do it like so -

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UItableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

You can set identifier from Interface Builder too -

[image]

Comment: I am not using storyboard, I am creating the cell programatically. So I don't think this solution might be applicable. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: hey man i provided the solution for both. Please read the answer properly. first i gave programatic solution then for the sake of completeness provided the IB solution too.

Comment: sorry about that, NSString CellIdentifier is set as @"Cell". Note the original code has been updated now. I am doing that, it is present in the code that i have pasted. Can you let me know if i am missing something. Still not working.

Answer (score 2):

This code should be generating the warning "control reaches end of non-void function" because you aren't actually returning anything. Add `return cell;` to the end of the function. Additionally, you never add the reuse identifier to the newly created cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: while pasting the code i had missed out a few lines, now i have edited  and updated. The code that you pasted is what I am using. Yet it returns nil every time.

Answer (score 1):

First declare **cell identifier** for a tableViewCell at the **viewDidLoad** method as:

```
[tableView registerClass:UITableViewCell.class forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
```

Now recall the instance of the UITableViewCell with the same identifier **"MyCell"** as:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Further just fill up the cell .. Now logic executes that limited number of cells are able to show enormously large list efficiently (using dequeue concept).

**But remember** to assign value (even nil if required) to every UIView used in the cell, otherwise overwriting / overlapping of text / images will happen.