# UITableView "cellForRowAtIndexPath" not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to use "`reloadData`" method on a `uitableView`, it seems like it works (both `dataSource` method are being called) and when I debug "`cellForRowAtIndexPath`" the cell that it returns is the correct cell) but I can't see the cell (`numberOfRowsInSection` is changing and adding blank space for each new cell - So it's not seems to be a threads problem). For example, if I have in the `tableView` 5 "names" (my data array called "namesArray") and I add 2 there will be 5 names and 2 nil cells presented on the `tableView`. The problem seems to be with `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

**cellForRowAtIndex:**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//Creating "cellIdentifier"(NSString) with "Cell" as the value
NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";

[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

//Creating a default cell using "cellIdentifier"(NSString)
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell==nil) {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text=[namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Returning cell
return cell;
}
```

**numberOfRowsInSection:**

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.namesArray.count;
}
```

---

```
-(void)addNameToNamesArray:(NSString*)name
 {
     [self.namesArray addObject:name];
     NSLog(@"namesArray lastObject: %@",[self.namesArray lastObject]);
    //NSLog print: The correct name (the one that was added)

    [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```

screenshot for "5 names and 2 nil cells":
[image: screenshot]
Do you have any idea what can it be?

Comment: can you paste code ?

Comment: please share some code.

Comment: @ArslanAsim updated the post, please take a look

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava updated the post, please take a look

Comment: What do you mean by nil cells? Could you post a screenshot perhaps?

Comment: Is the array initialized..? How about yuo paste the entire class here

Comment: use namesArray as datasource of your tableView,and also initialise your names array

Comment: @Jason updated post with a screenshot

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava It's really long class... but namesArray is initialized on "viewDidLoad"

Comment: @ArslanAsim that's what I do

Comment: @Yhper Is namesArray NSMutableArray? And How many times cellForRowAtIndexPath returning cell put counter int it ans NSLog it..

Comment: How could you tell that `it's adding blank space for each new cell`? I don't see any wrong about these codes. Could you `NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread isMainThread]);` in `addNameToNamesArray`?

Comment: @user3480295 it returns YES

Comment: @KrishnaKumar 7 times (namesArray.count==7)

Comment: @Yhper Post the whole code for the class..

Comment: I think it will be not possible to help you to find problem if you will not post here all code of `.m` file. If `delegate` is set and your `cellIdentifier` is correct - the the problem is that: you are adding new objects but then you rewrite it / or you are adding `empty names` - and that because you get empty cells. 1. Check new name before adding. 2. Check new array in `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: @Nazir Can you give me your email and I'll send you my project, maybe you'll be able to help?

Comment: @ArslanAsim Can you give me your email and I'll send you my project, maybe you'll be able to help?

Comment: Which is the place where you call addNameToNamesArray: method? if it is on a button press ...perhaps the button press is getting more than one time with empty data that gets added into your array or something like that.

Comment: @Yhper there is no way to public here email securely. Share link with project google/docs or dropbox

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you have updated the data in your array, but the table view hasn't accessed that data yet, leading to the nil cells that you see. Since your cells load properly with the initial 5 element in your array, it's probable that you simply haven't refreshed the table view's data. Try using [tableView reloadData] **after** you have added the new elements to your array.

---

**EDIT 1**
What about changing your cellForRowAtIndexPath code to this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Creating "cellIdentifier"(NSString) with "Cell" as the value
     NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";

    //Creating a default cell using "cellIdentifier"(NSString)
     UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

     cell.textLabel.text = [self.namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     NSLog(@"name: %@", cell.textLabel.text);

    //Returning cell
     return cell;
}
```

Let us know the output of NSLog.

Comment: That's what I do, updated the post with some code, please take a look

Comment: Shouldn't the "numberOfRowsInSection return self.namesArray.count?

Comment: It is return self.namesArray.count

Comment: No, it always was like that

Comment: Could you verify that "addNameToNamesArray" is being run on the main thread? Where is it being called?

Comment: And did you try removing the cell dequeue code, and replacing it with your own initialised cells?

Comment: Copy and paste the code I've got above and see what happens. It looks like it could be something to do with you reusing the cells. Otherwise the only other explanation to why they are nil is that they somehow are being run on a background thread.

Comment: Also, check your UITableView in Storyboard and make sure that you've added at least one prototype cell - with the identifier as "Cell". Refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379547/dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-always-returns-nil-not-using-storyboard

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//Creating "cellIdentifier"(NSString) with "Cell" as the value
static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";

//[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

//Creating a default cell using "cellIdentifier"(NSString)
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell==nil) {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text=[namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Returning cell
return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.namesArray.count;
}
```

set the outlet of tableview and then in addNameToNamesArray method after adding elements reload the tableview

Comment: Tried it, still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You call

```
[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

inside cellForRowAtIndexPath!

Don't you think that's a bit late? And if it worked, you would be calling it a bit often?

And if dequeue... returns nil when a class is registered, something is badly wrong.

Comment: Tried to move it to "viewDidLoad", same problem

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure you have initialized `self.namesArray` in `viewDidLoad`

Try the following:

```
[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

like below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
 }
```

Comment: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is always returns nil for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly alright. There can be some possibilities that its not working for you.

1. You are not initialising your datasource i.e NSMutableArray in your case.
2. It depends how you are calling addNameToNamesArray method.

If you can share your whole code for that class as how you are calling method and every delegates you are using.

Comment: Can you give me your email and I'll send you my project, maybe you'll be able to help?

Comment: @Yhper   relentless.krishna@gmail.com